# Problema ao acessar uma relação Um para Muitos no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Meu model Produto tem o seguinte relacionamento:

```
public function categoria(){
    return $this->belongsTo('estoque\Categoria');
}
```

e meu model Categoria tem:

```
public function produtos(){
        return $this->hasMany('estoque\Produto');
}
```

Ao tentar acessar na `view`:

```
<td> {{$p->categoria}} <td>
```

Me retorna :

```
{"id":1,"nome":"Cerveja","descricao":"Todas cervejas","ativo":1,"created_at":"2015-10-24 13:53:14","updated_at":"2015-10-24 13:53:14"}
```

Mas preciso só do nome da categoria, então estou tentando acessar assim:

```
<td> {{$p->categoria->nome}} <td>
```

Mas gera o seguinte erro:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

De acordo com a documentação no site do [Lavael](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many), eu poderia usar `{{$p->categoria->nome}}`, mas não consigo. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Rafael como está o seu model Categoria? Foi definido a relação inversa `hasOne` ?

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Tente utilizar como array `<td> {{$p->categoria['nome']}} <td>`

Comment: Sim isso funciona, mas eu tinha visto uns exemplos na internet e eles acessavam como objeto e não array.

Comment: Bem estranho Rafael, não consegui reproduzir o seu problema aqui. Tente atualizar com um `composer update`, eeu código está versionado em algum lugar?

Comment: Não esta no somente no meu pc, e realizei o `composer update`.

Comment: Já vi esse exemplo em algum lugar ...

Comment: Você tem algum algum produto relacionado com a categoria?

Comment: Nesse exemplo um produto pertence a uma categoria, mas não sei porque ele retorna uma array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É preciso definir a chave estrangeira na relação, então fica assim:

```
public function categoria(){
    return $this->belongsTo('estoque\Categoria', 'categoria_id');
}
```

Então só acessar como objeto:

```
<td> {{$p->categoria->nome}} <td>
```

Perguntei no SOen: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33870989/5165064)

Answer (score 1):

Rafael, pelo retorno que você me demonstra você **Não** Selecionou o campo referente ao relacionamento, se você utilizou a função `select`.

O problema  é que o Laravel 4 não consegue relacionar os itens internamente, quando você não os seleciona.

Então, se você estiver fazendo um select parecido parecido com esse:

```
User::select('nome', 'email')->with('role')->get();
```

Você deverá fazer isso (adicionar a chave de relacionamento entre os models):

```
User::select('nome', 'email', 'role_id')->with('role')->get();
```

Todas as vezes que tive problemas como esse, foi assim que resolvi.